# Android Studio - "The <activity> element must be a direct child of the <application> element [WrongManifestParent]"

Tags: android, android-studio, manifest

When I try to generate a APK, it comes up with this error in my AndroidManifest.xml. It says,

```
Error:(6) Error: The <activity> element must be a direct child of the <application> element [WrongManifestParent]
```

How do I fix this??

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

 package="com.apps.stephenshettler.laughsoundboard">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<activity
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
     android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|sc    reenSize|smallestScreenSize"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
<application
 android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You fix it my making all activities direct children of the application tag, as the error says... Voting to close as typo

Answer (score 2):

`<activity>` must comes inside the `<application>`. So use the below code in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

 package="com.apps.stephenshettler.laughsoundboard">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
 android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
     android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|sc    reenSize|smallestScreenSize"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

The message you are getting is pretty clear.
Just make sure that your manifest is well-structured.

Replace it with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

 package="com.apps.stephenshettler.laughsoundboard">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application
 android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
     android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|sc    reenSize|smallestScreenSize"
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Refer to the documentation: [App Manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)